# Searching for free and fast Jquery with Php Upload Script

Tags: php, jquery, file, upload, sharing

I'm looking for free php and jquery(would be nice) upload script which I could
include in my webpage.

It must be able to upload multiple files, and make a
link for them.. as in mysite.com/randomstuff with a list of files
or if I upload one file, then it will redirect to hotlink and then people
wont have to click anything.

It must have easy way to upload files without logging in
so that when I upload I could just give the link to my clients 
or friends so that they could download some support files, fixes, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:

http://www.uploadify.com/

It is easy to use jquery and php uploading method. you can upload multiple files at a time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For simple uploads (inc multiple files/good interface), this is what you need: http://www.uploadify.com/

However, it won't do all the url stuff for you. There may be another decent plugin for that. Or you could try some, you know, coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file upload script like the ones mentioned before, but I found that http://www.plupload.com/ is very nice to use. 
Anyway, you will still need to code some php to make it work the way you want.